# Print_r function doesn't work on first page refresh

Tags: php, cookies, printing, page-refresh

There is a simple question.
I've got 2 files; `index.php` and `functions.php`.
`index.php`:

```
<?php

require 'functions.php';

print_r($_COOKIE['blablabla'])

?>
```

Cookie initializes in `functions.php`.
So, i am going to `index.php` and see `print_r` result only on second page refresh.
So, the first refresh cookie sets, i can see it in browser privacy settings, but they are not printed.
Why does it happen?

Comment: Because the cookie has to be sent to the server after storing localy. And it will be sent once you recall the page/script. This time the cookie already exists and can be sent.

Comment: Don't you get an error because you forgot `;` after print_r?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using `setcookie();` you have to populate `$_COOKIE` yourself within the same process in order to access the values.

```
$key = 'variable';
$val = 'value123';
setcookie($key, $val, ...);
$_COOKIE[$key] = $val;
```

`$_COOKIE` usually has values from the browser request. The request happens **before** the server response.

```
Request (without cookie) ----> Response (with set cookie)
----> Second Request (with cookie) ----> Response
```

Answer (score 2):

As cookies are set on the browser, thus initially it is due to be set (code from functions.php) on first page refresh. Once cookie is set on browser then you are able to access it.